# Repeat values in list of list of lists based on count in list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists of lists like the following:

```
rep = [[[1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 43], 
        [6, 5, 2, 56, 4, 12], 
        [5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 7, 1]], 
       [[5, 3, 7, 3, 21], 
        [6, 2, 5, 2,1, 6, 2], 
        [78, 2, 65, 2, 6, 2], 
        [78, 2, 65, 2, 6, 2]]]
```

And a list of lists indicating the desired count of repeats

```
count = [[5, 2, 5], [5, 2, 4, 5]]
```

As you can see, the length of each element in `count` is identical to the length of each of the lists within `rep`.

I want to use `count` to repeat the inner most lists in `rep`.

For example, the output should look like:

```
out = [[[1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 43], 
        [1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 43], 
        [1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 43], 
        [1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 43], 
        [1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 43], 
        [6, 5, 2, 56, 4, 12], 
        [6, 5, 2, 56, 4, 12], 
        [5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 7, 1], 
        [5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 7, 1], 
        [5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 7, 1], 
        [5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 7, 1] 
        [5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 7, 1]], 
       [[5, 3, 7, 3, 21], 
        [5, 3, 7, 3, 21], 
        [5, 3, 7, 3, 21], 
        [5, 3, 7, 3, 21], 
        [5, 3, 7, 3, 21], 
        [6, 2, 5, 2,1, 6, 2], 
        [6, 2, 5, 2,1, 6, 2], 
        [78, 2, 65, 2, 6, 2], 
        [78, 2, 65, 2, 6, 2], 
        [78, 2, 65, 2, 6, 2], 
        [78, 2, 65, 2, 6, 2], 
        [78, 2, 98, 2, 6, 2], 
        [78, 2, 98, 2, 6, 2], 
        [78, 2, 98, 2, 6, 2], 
        [78, 2, 98, 2, 6, 2], 
        [78, 2, 98, 2, 6, 2]]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Who are you getting to upvote your question?

Comment: What code have you tried? What was the problem with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying the premise of the question, you're looking for a way to repeat a list.

```
>>> list = [1,2,3]
>>> count = 3
>>> [item for item in list for _ in range(count)]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Step up once, you have a list of lists that need repeating, and a list of repeat counts.

```
>>> lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> counts = [2, 1, 3]
>>> [l for l, c in zip(lists, counts) for _ in range(c)]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9]]
```

And the last iteration, again adding one level of nesting.

```
>>> lists = [[[1, 2], [2, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
>>> counts = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> [[l for l, c in zip(sublist, subcounts) for _ in range(c)] for sublist, subcounts in zip(lists, counts)]
[[[1, 2], [2, 4], [2, 4]], [[5, 6], [5, 6], [5, 6], [7, 8], [7, 8], [7, 8], [7, 8]]]
```

Comment: Lovely. Cheers for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested list-comprehension with `zip`:

```
res = [[x for x, y in zip(sub_a, sub_b) for _ in range(y)] for sub_a, sub_b in zip(rep, count)]
```

which for your example, returns:

```
[[[1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 43], 
  [1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 43], 
  [1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 43], 
  [1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 43], 
  [1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 43], 
  [6, 5, 2, 56, 4, 12], 
  [6, 5, 2, 56, 4, 12], 
  [5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 7, 1], 
  [5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 7, 1], 
  [5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 7, 1], 
  [5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 7, 1], 
  [5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 7, 1]], 
 [[5, 3, 7, 3, 21], ...]
```

> FYI: Your question is *programmatically* interesting; that is not where the down-votes come from. Not showing any effort is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of list comprehension with `zip`, `repeat`, and `reduce` to get your result.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
from itertools import repeat

[reduce(add, [list(repeat(r, c)) for r,c in zip(rp, cnt)]) for rp, cnt in zip(rep, count)]

# returns:
[[[1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 43],
  [1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 43],
  [1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 43],
  [1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 43],
  [1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 43],
  [6, 5, 2, 56, 4, 12],
  [6, 5, 2, 56, 4, 12],
  [5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 7, 1],
  [5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 7, 1],
  [5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 7, 1],
  [5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 7, 1],
  [5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 7, 1]],
 [[5, 3, 7, 3, 21],
  [5, 3, 7, 3, 21],
  [5, 3, 7, 3, 21],
  [5, 3, 7, 3, 21],
  [5, 3, 7, 3, 21],
  [6, 2, 5, 2, 1, 6, 2],
  [6, 2, 5, 2, 1, 6, 2],
  [78, 2, 65, 2, 6, 2],
  [78, 2, 65, 2, 6, 2],
  [78, 2, 65, 2, 6, 2],
  [78, 2, 65, 2, 6, 2],
  [78, 2, 65, 2, 6, 2],
  [78, 2, 65, 2, 6, 2],
  [78, 2, 65, 2, 6, 2],
  [78, 2, 65, 2, 6, 2],
  [78, 2, 65, 2, 6, 2]]]
```